# Is TCP Keepalive necessary for a busy TCP socket?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, ip

In this introduction article: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html

It states that reasons for TCP keep alive are:

- Preventing disconnection due to network inactivity
- Detect dead peers

So in my application, there is a busy TCP socket. Packets are frequently sent back and forth between the two peers - so there is a good amount of packets with ACK flag set.

The application protocol uses other means for dead peer detection.

Is TCP keepalive still necessary for the case above?

Comment: TCP keepalives are sent by default every two hours. That's not going to accomplish your first bullet point. The idea was just to detect dead peers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. TCP keepalive is practically a 0 byte-long tcp packet. If you can be sure on your app protocol, it is unneeded.